# Permutation model in which infinite sets are weakly Dedekind-infinite but not Dedekind-infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, model-theory

I’m trying to create a permutation model $N$ in which every infinite set is weakly Dedekind-infinite (i.e. for every infinite set $A\in N$ there is a surjective map $f:A\rightarrow\omega$ in $N$), but the model contains an infinite $B\in N$ which is not Dedekind-infinite (i.e. there is no injective function $f:\omega\rightarrow B$ in $N$). I’ve been struggling, so if anyone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Permutation or symmetric? The Cohen model is an easy example of a symmetric model with your wanted property. But both of its permutation "analogues" are not going to work (the First Fraenkel model and the Mostowski model).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was hoping to find a good permutation model to demonstrate that weakly Dedekind-infinite does not imply Dedekind-infinite, but I could definitely try it with a symmetric model. Any chance you would mind explaining briefly how you know the Cohen model is weakly Dedekind-infinite but not Dedekind infinite? I'm not particularly familiar with symmetric models

Comment: @JLB The "point" of the model is to have an infinite D-finite set of reals. See Jech Axiom of choice, exercise 5.20 for a sketch of the fact that infinite implies weakly D-infinite.

Comment: A quick search of Howard and Rubin says the second Fraenkel model (the one with the countable set of pairs of atoms) has the properties you're looking for. It's not hard to show $A$ is D-finite but weakly D-infinite. I don't see offhand if the same method in Jech from above works for transfering the fact that $A$ is weakly Dedekind infinite to every infinite set being so.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks that's very useful. Only issue is that, as you said, it seems pretty non-trivial that every infinite set is weakly Dedekind infinite. If you have any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JLB This may be overkill, but you can use the fact that the model satisfies multiple choice (see Jech theorem 9.2 (i)), and then it's not too hard to see that multiple choice implies every infinite set is weakly D-infinite (make a multiple choice from the sequence $X_n = \{A\subseteq X: |A| = n\}$ and use this to build a sequence of distinct subsets of $X$).

Comment: @JLB: In J.K. Truss 'Classes of Dedekind Cardinals' (1974), it states on the fourth page (page 190) that 'in the Halpren-Levy model, every infinite set has a countable patition but there is an infinite set with no countable subset.'  I think this model is found in Halpern-Levy 'The boolean prime ideal theorem does not imply the axiom of choice' (1974).  It's not ZFA though.

Comment: @ChadK: The Halpern–Levy model *is* the Cohen model.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: ok, I didn't have the Halpern-Levy paper to check.  Just went by Truss' statement, but I notice now that Truss refers to Cohen's monograph for a proof of this claim which is a kind of giveaway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second Fraenkel model (in the terminology of Jech's AOC monagraph, see section 4.4) is a permutation model that has these properties.

The model is constructed as follows: We start with countably-many atoms grouped like $A = \bigcup_n \{a_n,b_n\}$, consider the group of permutations $\pi$ such that for all $n,$ either $\pi a_n= a_n$ and $\pi b_n = b_n,$ or $\pi a_n= b_n$ and $\pi b_n = a_n$, and then take the permutation model $\mathcal V$ of this group with finite supports.

As usual for finite supports, $A$ is infinite and Dedekind-finite in $\mathcal V$:  For any $f:\omega \to A$ with infinite range and any finite $E\subseteq A,$ there is an $n$ such that $a_n,b_n\notin E$ and either $a_n$ or $b_n$ in the range of $f.$ Then the $\pi$ that just swaps $a_n$ and $b_n$ fixes $E$ and has $\pi f \ne f,$ and thus $f\notin \mathcal V.$

But unlike the other two permutation models Jech studies in chapter $4,$ note that $A$ is not weakly Dedekind-finite: The surjection $A\to \omega$ given by $a_n\mapsto n$ and $b_n\mapsto n$ is clearly symmetric with support $\emptyset$.

To show that every infinite set is weakly Dedekind-infinite in $\mathcal V,$ we can use the fact that $\mathcal V$ satisfies the axiom of multiple choice (i.e. for any collection $X$ of nonempty sets, there is a function $f$ on $X$ such that for all $x\in X,$ $f(x)$ is a finite subset of $x$), which is proven as part of Jech's theorem 9.2. The idea of the proof is that for any nonempty $X\in \mathcal V$ and $x\in X,$ the set $G(X,x) = \{\pi x: \pi X = X\}$ is finite, since $\pi x$ only determined by what $\pi$ does on the support of $x$, and is clearly unchanged by any $\pi$ with $\pi X= X.$ By choosing a canonical $X$ and $x$ in each orbit of the full group and defining $F(\rho X) = \rho G(X,x)$, we can see $F$ is a symmetric multiple choice function on $\mathcal V.$

So with that result, it just remains to show multiple choice implies every infinite set is weakly Dedekind-infinite. Let $X$ be infinite and for $n\in \omega,$ let $X_n = \{Y\subseteq X: |Y|=n\}.$ Let $Y_n$ be a multiple choice sequence from $X_n$ and let $Y'_n = \cup Y_n,$ so each $Y_n'$ is a finite subset of $X$ with size $\ge n.$ Then by finding the next $Y_n$ with new elements (which always will exist since the size keeps growing) and taking the new elements, we can get a sequence $Z_n$ of disjoint nonempty subsets of $X.$ Then for $x\in X,$ define $g(x)$ be the unique $n$ such that $x\in Z_n$ if $x\in \bigcup_n Z_n,$ and otherwise let $g(x) =0$, and $g$ is a surjection $X\to \omega.$

---

It should be noted that this only establishes independence of the two propositions over ZFA, and the argument seems unpromising to transfer to ZF since multiple choice is equivalent to choice over ZF. (Also, according to Howard and Rubin, which may be outdated, it's unknown if every infinite set is weakly Dedekind infinite in the second Cohen model.) However, as noted in the comments, the basic Cohen model witnesses independence over ZF, and exercise 5.20 in Jech sketches the argument.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks